# Microdata and not all content in same place

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I want to implement Schema.org [`LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness).

The site already exists and can NOT change the layout.

All the info need for `LocalBusiness` is NOT in one place on the page.

Someone suggested hiding some element for schema HTML but from what I know this is not a good idea.

Another suggestion was to have all schema code in one place and hide it and then have the content render again where needed for display on the page.
Example of code when hiding all schema:

```html
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
  <span itemprop="name" style="display:none">Seattle, WA</span> 
   <img itemprop="image" src="/img/myimage.jpg" alt="Seattle, WA" style="display:none">
  <span itemprop="description" style="display:none">some description text</span>
  <div itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress" style="display:none">
    <span itemprop="streetAddress">my street adderss</span> 
    <span itemprop="addressLocality">Blabla</span>, <span itemprop="addressRegion">WA</span>
  </div>
  <span itemprop="telephone" style="display:none"><a href="tel:123456789"> (123) 456-6789</a></span>
  <div itemprop="geo" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates" style="display:none">
    <meta itemprop="latitude" content="47.421356">
    <meta itemprop="longitude" content="-111.235178">
  </div>
</div>
```

The only way I can think of not hiding content and not changing page layout is to break up the `LocalBusiness` code but not sure if this is allowed or possible and if so how?

OR

Is it ok to wrap almost the whole page with

```html
<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
```

and use the rest of the code where needed throughout the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Wrap

Yes, you can wrap the whole content in such a `div`. You could also use the `body` or `html` element instead.

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
  <!-- all "itemprop" in here will belong to this "LocalBusiness",
       unless they are nested under another "itemscope" -->
</body>
```

#### `itemref`

Another option is to use the `itemref` attribute. It allows you to add properties from anywhere on the page to an item.

```html
<div id="a">
  <span itemprop="name">Seattle, WA</span>
  <img itemprop="image" src="img.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness" itemref="a b c">
</div>

<span id="b" itemprop="telephone">(123) 456-6789</span>

<div>
  <p id="c" itemprop="description">some description text</p>
</div>
```

You have to make sure that these referenced properties are not nested under another `itemscope`, otherwise they get added to this item, too.

#### Hide

If you need to hide elements for Microdata, use `link` (for URI values) and `meta` (for any other string values) elements. These two elements are hidden by default in the browser stylesheets.

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
  <meta itemprop="name" content="Seattle, WA">
  <link itemprop="image" href="img.jpg">
</div>
```